# How to prevent docker container from exit while not finished?

Tags: java, docker, gitlab, dockerfile

I have a `java` `spring-boot` import application that currently runs periodically by `cron`.

Now I'd like to migrate to `docker`, the app already runs fine inside a container (`docker-compose`) with:

`ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]`

Question: how can I prevent the docker container being killed by  `gitlab CIC/D` while my script is still running - when a new software version is being deployed? the docker host should wait until the script finished (how could I signal that to the host), and only then publish and run the new container version.

Comment: Docker should already keep the container running as long as the command specified in the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` values (or correlating command line arguments) is still running. If you're script simply sets up some conjobs then exits, you probably want to keep script "running" without doing any real work. A very naive example (but good proof of concept) would be an infinite loop

Comment: Are you sure? For example, if I run a spring-boot web application from `ENTRYPOINT`, it's kept alive just until a new deployment is initialized from docker. Then, the old container terminates automatically and the new starts up. So docker does not keep containers running...

Comment: Someone has to do that deployment of a new version. That's not something Docker does on it's own. Maybe you have some CI/CD set up that automatically deploys? If you run pure Docker, a container runs until the main process exits.

Comment: Excuse, yet I'm asking regarding (gitlab) `ci/cd` pipelines.

Comment: Please include your CI job configuration from your `.gitlab-ci.yml`